# Read Top 10 Records in a CSV through CPP

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

So I'm trying to write a program the reads a CSV file.  The file has information from Twitter users and includes username,screen name,id,link,number of records.  I need my program to find the top 5 users with the most tweets and my code is below:

```
    string screen_name;
    string user_class;
    string user_id;
    string user_link;
    int num_records;

    string str_num_records;

    getline(stream_s, screen_name, ',');
    getline(stream_s, user_class, ',');
    getline(stream_s, user_id, ',');
    getline(stream_s, user_link, ',');
    getline(stream_s, str_num_records);
    string user[5];
    int tweets[5];
    int top20=0;


    int req_recs = 750;
    cout<<"Please be patient as this may take up to 60 seconds"<<endl;

    while (top20<=4){
        if (num_records==req_recs){
            //cout << "records = " << str_num_records << endl;

            stringstream num_records_stream(str_num_records);
            num_records_stream >> num_records;
            cout << "User: "<<screen_name<<" has "<<num_records<<" records"<< endl;
            cout <<"\n\n";
                req_recs-=1;
                top20+=1;
        }
        else{
            req_recs-=1;
        }

    }
```

For some reason, whenever I run it, I produce the same record every single time, and when I try to call my arrays, I don't get a user name output and the number of records in the other array comes out in massively small or massively large number, or zero.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very good candidate to learn to use a debugger.  Using a debugger to step through the code, *watching* values of variables, is a lot faster than posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use my debugger, as there is not a compilable example that I can use; so you will have to use your debugger instead.

Comment: You could use `std::map`, like `std::map<std::string, int>` to count the number of users.  The `std::string` will be the User's name, the `int` will be the occurrences.

Comment: Please coordinate your title with the context.  The title says top 10, your question says top 5.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a structure to hold the fields.  Let the structure represent a record.

```
struct Record
{
    string screen_name;
    string user_class;
    string user_id;
    string user_link;
    unsigned int occurrences;
};
```

Use a container of these records, such as `std::vector`.
Read a record from the file (until there is an issue with the input file).
Search the container for a record with the same screen_name.
If exists, increment the `occurrences` field.

After all records are processed, sort the container by descending order of the `occurrences` field.
Print out the first 5 records.